# In Swift when false means true

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, boolean

Has anybody run into a case similar to what my picture below shows?

I have a variable `landingBools.didSlowPast40Knots` which (as you can see from the debug print out) is false but for some reason the if statement is evaluating as true.

Any ideas why this is happening?  Or is it just a random bug?

Looks like I'm not specifying the type ... i'll try make them : Bool

```
struct LandingBOOLs {
    var didDepart : Bool = false
    var didLand   : Bool = false
    var didSpeedOver40Knots : Bool = false
    var didSlowPast40Knots  : Bool = false

    func isLanded() -> Bool {
        return didDepart & didLand & didSpeedOver40Knots & didSlowPast40Knots
    }

}
```

[image]

*Followup*

I changed my code to:

```
if (lastPhase == .Descend && phaseOfFlightString == .LevelFlight) {
  if (landingBools.didDepart) {
    if (landingBools.didSlowPast40Knots) {             
       let landed = landingBools.didLand
       if (landed) {
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LANDED", object: self)
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

[image]

I'm now confused because my function is:

```
func isLanded() -> Bool {
  return didDepart & didLand & didSpeedOver40Knots & didSlowPast40Knots
}
```

so shouldn't let figure out its a bool and not assign it a value of 128?  Do I need to do && instead of &?

Comment: Is your `didSlowPast40Knots` an `NSNumber` with false as a value (equivalent of `@NO` in ObjC) or is it scalar type as `bool`? Also - how does your declaration of property in question look like?

Comment: Can you log value of landingBools.didSlowPast40Knots before if check and log another one inside if and add else case with last log of the value. I believe it's true but the log from the console can show not most up to dated value. You can also change the condition by adding == true.

Comment: As with Greg, I'd be more inclined to believe that lldb was acting up; I've seen some odd results with it with Swift. Try some `println`s or `NSLog`s to confirm. (Also, try cleaning and rebuilding your project; I suppose there's a chance the debugging symbols/source is out of sync with the actual code...)

Comment: I'm going to update the code with a clean and some more printouts and then i'll be back on here..

Comment: In answer to your latest question, yes, you should use `&&` in your statement. [`&` is for bitwise operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html), and isn't appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A clean build seems to fix everything.

Comment: Cool. I'd guess at some point the build system got confused, and you were running different code from the source you were allegedly stepping through. Life can get very confusing at that stage.